# SQL not calculating TOTAL of selected columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, case, window-functions

I need to calculate the total value of a specific range of product codes. The product codes I need the calculation done on are 5780 and everything under 5700.

To get the total value I need the total cost of those products as well as the yield.

```
Value = Pirce * Yield %
```

To calculate the yield I use the equation:

```
 CASE 
    WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870
            THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
    WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730
            THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
    WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990
            THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
    ELSE Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits
END
```

The price is already in the system so I don't need to calculate that.

I have tried several equations to calculate the total value but none of them return the desired amount.

I feel like it should be similar to this equation but this just displays the value for each row as opposed to one total value:

```
SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (
        PARTITION BY (
            CASE 
                WHEN PC.ProductCategoryCode = 5780
                    OR [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] < 5700
                    THEN PC.ProductCategoryCode
                END
            )
        ) * ICP.UnitCost
```

This equation displays one total sum but the total is incorrect:

```
CASE 
    WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5780 OR [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] < 5700
        THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits * [ICP].[UnitCost]) OVER ()
END
```

I think that maybe I need the SUM of the UnitCost as well but when I try to do that inside the equation I get errors.

Sample Table:

```
Credits        375.00   

Product Code| Weight    | Yield     |Unit Cost| Value           
Pizza       |   150.00  | 40.00%    |   $2.25 | 0.900000    
Potato Chips|   25.00   | 6.60%     |   $1.00 | 0.06600 
Hot Dog     |   125.00  | 33.00%    |   $2.00 | 0.66000 
Soda        |   50.00   | 13.00%    |   $1.50 | 0.195000    
-------------------------------------------------------------
Total       |   350.00  |                     | 1.821000    
Total Value = 1.821000
```

Another sample explaining how I want only certain product codes:

---

```
Product Category Code | Value  |
----------------------x--------x
5870                  | 100    |
5730                  | 400    |
5990                  | 200    |
5780                  | 200    |
1111                  | 50     |  
2222                  | 175    |  
3333                  | 500    |  
4444                  | 125    |
```

> Total Value: 1050 
>       It has to ignore product code 5870, 5990, and 5730 and not include 
>       those in the total value.

I am using Microsoft SQL Sever 2005. Let me know if I need to explain further.

**Full Code:**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Credits DECIMAL(19, 8);
DECLARE @Price DECIMAL(19, 8);

SET @Credits = 41000;
SET @Price = 1.57;

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870
            THEN 'Trimmings'
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730
            THEN 'Rib Tips'
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990
            THEN 'Skins'
        ELSE [PC].[Description1]
        END AS [Description]
    ,SUM(SUM(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY (
            CASE 
                WHEN PC.ProductCategoryCode IN (
                        5870
                        ,5730
                        ,5990
                        )
                    THEN PC.ProductCategoryCode
                END
            )
        ) AS [Total Weight]
    ,Sum(CASE 
            WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] <> 5870
                THEN [PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]
            WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] <> 5730
                THEN [PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]
            WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] <> 5990
                THEN [PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]
            END) AS [Weight]
    ,@Credits - SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS [Shrink]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870
            THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730
            THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990
            THEN SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
        ELSE Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits
        END AS [Yield]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870
            THEN [ICP].[UnitCost]
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730
            THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] - 0.25
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990
            THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] * 0
        ELSE [ICP].[UnitCost]
        END AS [UC]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870
            THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730
            THEN ([ICP].[UnitCost] - 0.25) * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990
            THEN ([ICP].[UnitCost] * 0) * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
        ELSE [ICP].[UnitCost] * SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY [PC].[ProductCategoryCode])
        END AS [Value]
    ,SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]) / @Credits) OVER (
        PARTITION BY (
            CASE 
                WHEN PC.ProductCategoryCode = 5780
                    OR [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] < 5700
                    THEN PC.ProductCategoryCode
                END
            )
        ) * ICP.UnitCost AS [TotalValue]
FROM (
    (
        (
            (
                IC_Products [PC] INNER JOIN DC_Transactions [DCT] ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
                ) INNER JOIN AR_Customers [ARC] ON [DCT].CustomerKey = [ARC].CustomerKey
            ) INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots [PL] ON [DCT].LotKey = [PL].LotKey
        ) LEFT JOIN IC_ProductCosts [ICP] ON ICP.ProductKey = PC.ProductKey
        AND ICP.ProductCostCode = 5
    )
WHERE (
        [PL].ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-07-10 00:00:00' }
        AND (
            [PL].ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-07-10 00:00:00' }
            OR [PL].ProductionDate IS NULL
            )
        )
    AND (
        (1 = 1)
        AND [ARC].CustomerKey IN (39)
        )
GROUP BY CASE 
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870
            THEN 'Trimmings'
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730
            THEN 'Rib Tips'
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990
            THEN 'Skins'
        ELSE [PC].[Description1]
        END
    ,[ARC].CustomerKey
    ,[PC].ProductCategoryCode
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5870
            THEN [ICP].[UnitCost]
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5730
            THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] - 0.25
        WHEN [PC].[ProductCategoryCode] = 5990
            THEN [ICP].[UnitCost] * 0
        ELSE [ICP].[UnitCost]
        END
    ,[ICP].UnitCost
    ,[PC].ProcessCode
ORDER BY @Credits - SUM(Sum([PL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER ()
    ,SUM(SUM(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY (
            CASE 
                WHEN PC.ProductCategoryCode IN (
                        5870
                        ,5730
                        ,5990
                        )
                    THEN PC.ProductCategoryCode
                END
            )
        )
```

Comment: SQL Server 2005 does not even support windowing functions (i.e. `OVER` and `PARTITION BY`, etc.).  So, unless you can get to SQL Svr 2012, you need to rethink your approach

Comment: Any chance you could provide a sample set and desired output?  I'm not sure from your query what you're after exactly.

Comment: @SlimsGhost SQL Server 2005 does support them:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @HartCO yes, I put a table there that shows the desired output. Does that help or would you like more information involved with it?

Comment: @SlimsGhost it supports them, they work in this report for other equations and I have used them in other reports as well.

Comment: @Austin You probably should provide some sample data from your base tables. Otherwise, nobody will know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @FutbolFan I have created some sample data. Does that help?

Comment: @Austin Where is the IC_Products table sample at? I think that would be important.

Comment: @FutbolFan what do you mean where is it? It's alias is PC if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I don't think your sample data makes any sense here. Which table is that from?

Comment: @FutbolFan for the sample table I tried to make it easier to understand so I replaced the product codes (ints) with common known foods. For example, pizza's product category code may be 5870 and that number comes from IC_Products.ProductCategoryCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this may not work exactly the way you want. But, I have tried to cleanup your code which took a lot of time, but as far as I can see you may not even need the windowed version of `SUM` function. `Note: the query below may not properly compile as I do not have exact sample data to test this sample code.`

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Credits DECIMAL(19, 8);
DECLARE @Price DECIMAL(19, 8);

SET @Credits = 41000;
SET @Price = 1.57;

BEGIN
SELECT q1.[Description],
       q1.[Total Weight],
       q1.Shrink,
       q1.Yield,
       q1.UC,
       sum(q1.[Value]) AS [Total_Value] 
FROM 
(
--Product codes 5870 and less than 5700
SELECT 
     PC.Description1                                                                            AS [Description]
    ,SUM(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)                                                               AS [Total Weight]
    --,Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)                                                             AS [Weight]                     
    ,@Credits - Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)                                                    AS [Shrink]
    ,(Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk) / @Credits)                                                  AS [Yield]
    ,ICP.UnitCost                                                                               AS [UC]
    ,ICP.UnitCost * (Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk) / @Credits)                                   AS [Value]
FROM IC_Products PC 
INNER JOIN DC_Transactions DCT ON PC.ProductKey = DCT.ProductKey
INNER JOIN AR_Customers ARC ON DCT.CustomerKey = ARC.CustomerKey
INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots PL ON DCT.LotKey = PL.LotKey
LEFT JOIN IC_ProductCosts ICP ON ICP.ProductKey = PC.ProductKey
                              AND ICP.ProductCostCode = 5
WHERE ((PL.ProductionDate >= '2015-07-10 00:00:00' AND PL.ProductionDate <= '2015-07-10 00:00:00') OR PL.ProductionDate IS NULL)    
 AND  ARC.CustomerKey = 39
 AND (PC.ProductCategoryCode = 5780 OR PC.ProductCategoryCode < 5700)   --add this check in your where clause to limit to product codes you are interested in

GROUP BY 
     PC.Description1
    ,ARC.CustomerKey
    ,PC.ProductCategoryCode
    ,ICP.UnitCost
    ,PL.ProductionDate

UNION ALL

--Other Product codes 
SELECT 
     PC.Description1                                                                            AS [Description]
    ,SUM(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)                                                               AS [Total Weight]
    --,Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)                                                             AS [Weight]                   
    ,@Credits - Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk)                                                    AS [Shrink]
    ,(Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk) / @Credits)                                                  AS [Yield]
    ,ICP.UnitCost                                                                               AS [UC]
    ,ICP.UnitCost * (Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk) / @Credits)                                   AS [Value]
    ,(Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk) / @Credits)* ICP.UnitCost                                    AS [TotalValue]
FROM IC_Products PC 
INNER JOIN DC_Transactions DCT ON PC.ProductKey = DCT.ProductKey
INNER JOIN AR_Customers ARC ON DCT.CustomerKey = ARC.CustomerKey
INNER JOIN IC_ProductLots PL ON DCT.LotKey = PL.LotKey
LEFT JOIN IC_ProductCosts ICP ON ICP.ProductKey = PC.ProductKey
                              AND ICP.ProductCostCode = 5
WHERE ((PL.ProductionDate >= '2015-07-10 00:00:00' AND PL.ProductionDate <= '2015-07-10 00:00:00') OR PL.ProductionDate IS NULL)    
 AND  ARC.CustomerKey = 39
 AND (PC.ProductCategoryCode <> 5780 OR PC.ProductCategoryCode > 5700)   --add this check in your where clause to limit to product codes you are interested in

GROUP BY 
     PC.Description1
    ,ARC.CustomerKey
    ,PC.ProductCategoryCode
    ,ICP.UnitCost
    ,PL.ProductionDate
) AS q1
GROUP BY q1.[Description],
         q1.[Total Weight],
         q1.Shrink,
         q1.Yield,
         q1.UC
END
```

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know the result. Thank you.

Comment: After a quick look at OP's query I was thinking the same thing. I'll look closer and upvote later.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yeah I figured that he is just trying to do some aggregate calculations.

Comment: @futbolfan okay so I followed this as best as I could however I can't make that my WHERE statement because this report still needs to include other product codes. The only reason I need to use 5780 and < 5700 is because those all get grouped together but other product codes will still be in the report, just not grouped with those ones. In my old code my VALUE was incorrect and I did not realize that but now it prints on the correct answer so you did fix that but for TOTAL VALUE it is displaying the same numbers that it does for VALUE.

Comment: @FutbolFan I ended up using this code: SUM(ICP.UnitCost * (Sum(PL.OriginalQuantity_Stk) / @Credits)) OVER
       (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN PC.ProductCategoryCode IN (5870, 5730, 5990)
                           THEN PC.ProductCategoryCode
                      END)
       ) and it worked. But I would not have gotten the right answer if you didn't correct my VALUE calculation so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are after:

```
SELECT otherColumns, 
       SUM(
        CASE WHEN ProductCategoryCode < 5700 OR ProductCategoryCode=5780 
             THEN OriginalQuantity_Stk 
             ELSE 0 
        END
       ) OVER () / @credits * UnitCost AS tova 
FROM JoinedTables -- WHERE ...
```

The `CASE`clause needs to be fully included in the `SUM()` aggregate function, then divide the result by `@credits` and multiply with `UnitCost` *after* the `OVER ()` clause.

Since your originally posted query is a bit unwieldy I created a little [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4834c/3) with only a few columns that should demonstrate how my version of the query basically works (the column `UnitCost` contains arbitrary values I made up).

Comment: I've tried something similiar to this and it returns an error that there is a problem by OVER. I think it is because the parenthesis for SUM needs to close right before OVER.

Comment: You are right in a way! Not the `SUM()`, but the factors need to be put *after* the `OVER ()` clause (see my edit), then it *will* work!

Comment: when I do that I get the error "Column 'IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I tried to fix it by adding another SUM() to the beginning and closing it out at the same spot the other SUM closes but that prints a different value for each row.

Comment: @HartCO yeah that's what I tried and it got rid of the error but it doesn't produce the right total.